# Inserting data into a column using switch case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to use switch case in order to insert data into a column in database!
here is my code but its not working!

```
insert into fr(q) 
values((select
            case 
               when totalDue > 1000 then 'high'
               else 'Low'
            end as q
        from fr))
```

Comment: With only a partial snippet (I hope it's a partial snippet), it's hard to guess what the complete SQL was, but you may need to add a keyword, ( `select`),  at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that a valid `insert` statement, take out the `values ()` part of your code:

```
insert into fr (q)
  select 
    case 
      when totalDue > 1000 
        then 'high' 
      else 'Low' 
      end as q
    from fr
```

Although I think you're probably trying to `update` the table instead of `insert` rows into it.

```
update fr
  set q = case 
      when totalDue > 1000 
        then 'high' 
      else 'Low' 
      end;
```